# How to set a texture filter

Tags: libgdx

How important is it to set a texture filter?

In the book [Java Game Development with LibGDX](https://www.google.no/search?client=opera&q=java+game+development+with+libgdx&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) in chapter 3 they set a texture filter.

When I load video assets with the assetmanager I can't convert a textureregion to a texture to set the texture filter.

But I can however set a texture filter on the entire spritesheet like so:

```
textureAtlas = assetManager.get("images/packed/game.pack.atlas") // all images are found in this global static variable
        textureAtlas!!.findRegion("button").texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear)
```

How important is it to set a texture filter? Is this an ok solution? How can I get the textures from the atlas?

Comment: There's a good guide/tutorial about texture filters in libgdx at https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/texture-filter/.

Comment: Thank you, I now know more about which filter to apply when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textures always have a filter. If you don't set one, it will have the default filter of (Nearest, Nearest). This filter is appropriate for retro graphics (pixellated look). Otherwise, you'll most likely want to use (MipMapLinearLinear, Linear). If your game is mostly done and you've identified sprite drawing as a performance bottle-neck, then you can downgrade to (MipMapLinearNearest, Linear).

When creating an atlas using the TexturePacker, there is an option for texture filter, and if you set that you don't have to set it after you load the TextureAtlas in your game. You could also add a line at the top of your pack file like this:

```
filter: MipMapLinearLinear,Linear
```

Otherwise, if you want to set it on the atlas, it is fine with a single-page atlas to do what you did, and apply the filter using a texture reference from any of the texture regions, since they are all referencing the same Texture instance. But TextureAtlases can have multiple pages, so it would be more appropriate to do this:

```
for (Texture texture : textureAtlas.getTextures())
    texture.setFilter(...);
```

**Edit:** To add settings to a TexturePacker build, put a text file named pack.json in the directory with the source images. You only have to add the settings that you want to change from the defaults. LibGDX can read simplified json that omits quotation marks for elements with no whitespace. So to just set the texture filter, this is all you need in the file:

```
{
    filterMin: MipMapLinearLinear,
    filterMag: Linear
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes me happy.
It was however not clear how to actually add settings in the [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#settings), could you elaborate on how to do this? Seems like a good idea to just do it in the build.gradle file.

Comment: Not the build.gradle file, but a pack.json file. See edit above.